# Leaflet : How to create marker labels based on JSON fetched from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, express, leaflet

Users are shown points to press. When clicking a point, a menu pops up with text. I've been able to set down points, but when I try to retrieve data from my database when clicking a point, it shows does not show the marker specific information.

```
    for (pointer of pointers) {

        title.textContent = "No description available.";
        if (item.objDescription) {
            title.textContent = item.objDescription;
        }
        div.appendChild(title);

        menu.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong? I need the pointers to only show their own text and not every textfrom the database.

EDIT :

The issue title was updated to better reflect the desired solution.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: @TelmoDias The output is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: From the looks of it, you are not receiving 1 iterable object from the api but several, which anyway doesn't make a lot of sense, since you are able to create the several markers. Can you show a screenshot of the "Response" panel inside the "Network" panel of browser devtools , when you click the request that was made to the api ?

Comment: @TelmoDias I edited my post and added the screenshots, many thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Can you copy/paste the whole JSON from the response ?

Comment: @TelmoDias I edited my post and added the whole JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is ok, and your code for iterating on the response JSON object seems ok too.

I don't know what the code for `openobjectMenu` is, but from what I can see, you are creating the divs and already adding them inside of an element with id `objectMenuBody` (most likely on your html code). This makes it so that they are visible since the beginning.

I'm guessing you are using Leaflet because of the `L.marker` on your code.

I think think what you want to do is to add labels to markers, so most likely using the `marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.")` is the proper way to go.

You have an example here https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ .

So instead of this code you wrote :

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
        const title = document.createElement("h2");
        const lineBreak = document.createElement('br');

        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", "images/default.png");
        image.setAttribute("alt", "Default image");

        title.textContent = "No description available.";
        if (item.objDescription) {
            title.textContent = item.objDescription;
        }
        div.appendChild(title);
        div.appendChild(lineBreak);
```

You would just directly build a string with the HTML that you should pass to the `.bindPopup` method.

Quick example:

```
const pp = `<div><h2>${item.objDescription}</h2><img src="${item.image64}" /></div>`;
const marker = L.marker([item.lat, item.lon]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup(pp);
```

Comment: This is the approach I have decided to take, many thanks!